# I am trying to display the pictures that I took and I stored in firebase, but its not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

When I click on an icon, it is taking me to the GalleryScreen, which is where the images that I took previously in my app should be displayed. The images are being stored fine, but they are not being displayed.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class GalleryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GalleryScreen({super.key, required this.images, this.userId = ''});

  final List<File> images;
  final String userId;

  @override
  State<GalleryScreen> createState() {
    return _GalleryScreenState();
  }
}

final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

class _GalleryScreenState extends State<GalleryScreen> {
  // late List<File> _galleryImages;
      late List<GalleryImage> _galleryImages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadGalleryImages();
    _galleryImages;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _loadGalleryImages() async {
    try {
      if (widget.userId.isNotEmpty) {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('images')
            .doc(widget.userId)
            .collection('user_images')
            .get();

        print('NUMBER OF DOCUMENTS ${querySnapshot.size}');

        List<GalleryImage> images = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          return GalleryImage(
              file: File(doc['imagePath']), caption: doc['caption']);
        }).toList();

        setState(() {
          _galleryImages = images;
        });
      } else {
        print('USER ID IS EMPTY');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('ERROR LOADING GALLERY IMAGES $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Photo gallery',
        ),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
        ),
        itemCount: _galleryImages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GridTile(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Image.file(
                    _galleryImages[index].file,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  _galleryImages[index].caption,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
            },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GalleryImage {
  GalleryImage({required this.file, required this.caption});

  final File file;
  final String caption;
}
```

I tried to change the image.file in my expanded to image.network, but nothing changed. I also tried to use the Future instead of the GridView.build(), but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListTile(
        title: Text(report.title),
        subtitle: Text(report.description),
        leading: report.imageUrl.isNotEmpty
            ? Image.network(
                report.imageUrl,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
            : Container(width: 50, height: 50),
```

Instead of using the GridTile you can use this ListTile wherein the Image network is called and placed in the respected container. You should not find any difficulties using this.

Example usage-

```
  void _addReport(String title, String description, String imageUrl) {
controller.addReport(title, description, imageUrl);

// Add data to Firestore
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user_reports').add({
  'title': title,
  'description': description,
  'imageUrl': imageUrl,
});
```

}